# translate animations behaving oddly on IE11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, css-animations

I've been investigating and odd behavior when viewing CSS animations on IE11. I've dug up multiple instances where IE11 struggles to digest CSS animations similar to Chrome/Firefox, but, I'd like to produce a solution to this "bug" once and for all.

**Demonstration of behavior:** http://recordit.co/6urL1s8XgR

As you can see, when the user interacts with the "button", the intended animation is to slide in from the bottom right, scale up and set the opacity to 1. A *generic* representation of the approach below:

```
.element {
   ...
   opacity: 1;
   animation: animate 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}

@keyframes animate {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) translate3d(0, 0, 500px);
    }
}
```

However, on IE11, it complete's the animation lower within the DOM than other browsers, causing the animated element to "jump up" from where it (incorrectly) ended (the animation), to where it **needed** to finish.

A similar demonstration can be observed at the following url: https://chemonics.com/region/

Comment: re: https://chemonics.com/region/ you have several MARKUP errors with unmatched end tags. eg. HTML1509: Unmatched end tag.
region (678,1). Please correct those errors. To debug markup errors in IE first go Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. You could also use the w3c validator at validator.w3c.org/nu , using the direct input method.

Comment: @RobParsons – thanks for the feedback, unfortunately, these were all minimal 1509 errors (duplicate <p> tags due to how the WordPress wysiwyg handles things by default). I ended up isolating and solving this issue for the lack of an animation-fill-mode property of "forwards" being present.

Comment: thanks joey for the feedback about your Wordpress editor and the solution you found.When I see markup errors, I immediately suspect that you have not used the f12 tool at all to try to debug your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue with isolating the problem being the animation-fill-mode property of "forwards" was not present. This was causing the animation to (which only had a 0% keyframe defined for the animation) to end (at 100%) by inheriting the styles of the elements initial state (prior to the animation). With more modern browsers, they "fill in the gaps" whereas with IE11, well, it jumps between the gaps.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations-1/#valdef-animation-fill-mode-forwards